# css is showing two times in browser

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using wordpress and when i am inspecting element through firebug all the css rules are repeating .repeating rules are having same rules and same page no same style .I don't know what is the issue . Can any body help me about this to solve . the css in the fire bug is like this

```
#nav ul li a {     appkara/style.css?ver=2013-07-18(line 44)
    color: #666666;
    display: block;
    font: 400 14px 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    padding: 19px;
}
#nav ul li a {     appkara/style.css?ver=1.0.0(line 44)
    color: #666666;
    display: block;
    font: 400 14px 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    padding: 19px;
}
```

Comment: If you have  master page just put your CSS on this page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it could be a cache issue. You may be loading the exact same css file-  “style.css” -twice.
The “?ver=…“  is called a query string and it does’t do anything to the css file - it just allows Wordpress or your browser to know if there’s a change to the css file so it can refresh/change the cache. 
First, try clearing your cache locally.  If that doesn’t work try clearing the cache in Wordpress (it may be a plugin you installed).

Answer (score 0):

wordpress automatically loads the style.css file , you no need to call that css file manually from your head tag.. comment link tag in your head tag and check it out , wheather the problem exist or not..